# 2 instances of Redis: as a cache and as a persistent datastore

Tags: caching, redis

I want to setup 2 instances of Redis because I have different requirements for the data I want to store in Redis. While I sometimes do not mind losing some data that are used primarly as cached data, I want to avoid to lose some data in some cases like when I use python RQ that stores into Redis the jobs to execute.

I mentionned below the main settings to achieve such a goal.

What do you think?

Did I forget anything important?

1) Redis as a cache

```
# Snapshotting to not rebuild the whole cache if it has to restart
# Be reasonable to not decrease the performances
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

# Define a max memory and remove less recently used keys
maxmemory X  # To define according needs
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
maxmemory-samples 5

# The rdb file name
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory.
dir ./

# Make sure appendonly is disabled
appendonly no
```

2) Redis as a persistent datastore

```
# Disable snapshotting since we will save each request, see appendonly
save ""

# No limit in memory
# How to disable it? By not defining it in the config file?
maxmemory

# Enable appendonly
appendonly yes
appendfilename redis-aof.aof
appendfsync always # Save on each request to not lose any data
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no

# Rewrite the AOL file, choose a good min size based on the approximate size of the DB?
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 32mb

aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes

aof-load-truncated yes
```

Sources:

- http://redis.io/topics/persistence
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf
- http://fr.slideshare.net/eugef/redis-persistence-in-practice-1
- http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html
- [How to perform Persistence Store in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909282/how-to-perform-persistence-store-in-redis)
- https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/implementing-persistence-redis-intermediate

Answer (score 4):

I think your persistence options are too aggressive - but it mostly depends on the nature and the volume of your data.

For the cache, using RDB is a good idea, but keep in mind that depending on the volume of data, dumping the content of the memory on disk has a cost. On my system, Redis can write memory data at 400 MB/s, but note that data may (or may not) be compressed, may (or may not) be using dense data structures, so your mileage will vary. With your settings, a cache supporting heavy writing will generate a dump every minute. You have to check that with the volume you have, the dump duration is well below that minute (something like 6-10 seconds would be fine). Actually, I would recommend to keep only save 900 1 and remove the other save lines. And even a dump every 15 min could be considered as too frequent, especially if you have SSD hardware that will progressively wear out.

For the persistent store, you need to define also the dir parameter (since it also controls the location of the AOF file). The appendfsync always option is overkill and too slow for most purposes, except if you have very low throughput. You should set it to everysec. If you cannot afford to lose a single bit of data even in case of system crash, then using Redis as a storage backend is not a good idea. Finally, you will probably have to adjust auto-aof-rewrite-percentage and auto-aof-rewrite-min-size to the level of write throughput the Redis instance has to sustain.

Comment: Why are the persistence options too aggressive? I do not want to lose any data on this Redis instance. Aren't the settings appropriate then? I am not going to store a lot in it, it will not be my main datastore.
As for the cache, I will change the save to "1800 1". That should be enough. As a cache, I do not mind losing some data. Thanks

Comment: The settings are appropriate to avoid losing any data, but in practice, the price is too high. Each write operation will result in a synchronous fsync resulting of a total freeze of Redis for a few milliseconds. During those milliseconds, the instance will become totally unresponsive, and not just for a single connection - for all connections. Generally, it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with @Didier - this is more of a supplement rather than a full answer.

First note that Redis offers tunable persistency - you can use RDB and/or AOF. While a your choice of using RDB for a persistent cache makes perfect sense, I would recommend considering using both for your persistent store. This will allow you both point-in-time recovery based on the snapshots (i.e. backup) as well as post-crash recovery to the last recorded operation with the AOF.

For the persistent store, you **don't** want to set `maxmemory` to 0 (which is the default if it is commented out in the conf file). When set to 0, Redis will use as much memory as the OS will give it so eventually, as your dataset grows, you will run into a situation where the OS will kill it to free memory (this often happens when you least expect it ;)). You should, instead, use a real value that's based on the amount of RAM that your server has with enough padding for the OS. For example, if your server has 16GB of RAM, as a rule of thumb I'd restrict Redis from using more than 14GB.

But there's a catch. Since you've read everything about Redis' persistency, you probably remember that Redis forks to write the data to disk. Forking can more than double the memory consumption (forked copy + changes) during the child process' execution so you need to make sure that your server has enough free memory to accommodate that if you use data persistence. Also note that you should consider in your maxmemory calculation other potential memory-consuming thingies such as replication and client buffers depending on what/how you and the app use Redis.